# IBM MobileFirst Platform 6.3 Operational Analytics Failed installation for Tomcat

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

I have installed MobileFirst 6.3 appcenter console, worklight console successfully, they are operating fine on Tomcat/7.0.57. However when I try to install Operational Analytics, the documentation has the following

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_installation_tomcat.html

I am using tomcat manager http://localhost:8080/html to deploy the war files. logging in as manager, with the manager-gui role.

worklight-analytics.war - deployed with no issues
when I select the worklight-analytics-service.war file and deploy in the GUI, it throws a blank page first, indicating "connection error", and when I refresh the page, on the status bar in Tomcat manager GUI, I get this message - "FAIL - Tried to use command /upload via a GET request but POST is required";

Please provide some direction on what I need to do get this fixed. I am not sure If I have provided all required information - please bear with me and ask, if anything relevant (obviously I can't figure out what is relevant yet) is required to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to reproduce your error and I saw this in the logs:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException:
>   the request was rejected because its size (57353297) exceeds the
>   configured maximum (52428800)

It looks like by default, the web UI will only upload WARs of size 50MB or smaller. The analytics service WAR file is larger than this, so that is why this is failing. I was able to increase the limit by modifying the following lines in

> /webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<max-file-size>100000000</max-file-size>
<max-request-size>100000000</max-request-size>
```

This will increase the limit to 100MB. After I did this, I was able to successfully deploy the service WAR.

Just as a heads up, once you get the WAR deployed, you'll be presented with the login page. You'll need a tomcat user with the 'worklightadmin' role in order to get past the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

The worklight-analytics-service WAR file does not have a user interface. It is simply referenced by the worklight-analytics WAR file. When both WARs have been deployed, can you see the analytics console? And does data load just fine? If so, then everything is fine. There is only an issue if you are unable to use the user interface provided by the worklight-analytics WAR file.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I am unable to see the user interface provided by the worklight-analytics WAR file. I do not even see the worklight-analytics-service app in the list of deployed apps in Tomcat - thanks much for the help