# mvn tomcat7:deploy - Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Broken pipe

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7

I'm getting an error trying to deploy the CLIFF .war to my tomcat7 server.
[image]

[image]

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) on project cliff: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused: Connection refused

OS X 10.10.5
Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
JVM 1.8.0_05-b13

```
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:CLIFF davidlaxer$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T09:37:52-08:00)
Maven home: /Users/davidlaxer/Downloads/apache-maven-3.2.1
Java version: 1.8.0_05, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:CLIFF davidlaxer$ 


David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:CLIFF davidlaxer$ sudo mvn tomcat7:deploy -DskipTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] CLIFF
[INFO] common
[INFO] stanford-entity-extractor
[INFO] cliff
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CLIFF 2.3.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ CLIFF >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ CLIFF <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ CLIFF ---
[INFO] Skipping non-war project
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building common 2.3.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ common >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ common ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/davidlaxer/CLIFF/common/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ common ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ common ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/davidlaxer/CLIFF/common/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ common ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) @ common ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ common ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ common <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ common ---
[INFO] Skipping non-war project
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building stanford-entity-extractor 2.3.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ stanford-entity-extractor >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ stanford-entity-extractor ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 14 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ stanford-entity-extractor ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ stanford-entity-extractor ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 23 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ stanford-entity-extractor ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) @ stanford-entity-extractor ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ stanford-entity-extractor ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ stanford-entity-extractor <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ stanford-entity-extractor ---
[INFO] Skipping non-war project
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building cliff 2.3.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ cliff >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ cliff ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ cliff ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ cliff ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/davidlaxer/CLIFF/webapp/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ cliff ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) @ cliff ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ cliff ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [cliff] in [/Users/davidlaxer/CLIFF/webapp/target/cliff-2.3.0]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/Users/davidlaxer/CLIFF/webapp/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1345 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /Users/davidlaxer/CLIFF/webapp/target/cliff-2.3.0.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ cliff <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ cliff ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/cliff-2.3.0  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] CLIFF ............................................. SUCCESS [  1.728 s]
[INFO] common ............................................ SUCCESS [  1.883 s]
[INFO] stanford-entity-extractor ......................... SUCCESS [  0.265 s]
[INFO] cliff ............................................. FAILURE [ 11.384 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.717 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-26T08:07:32-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) on project cliff: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ConnectException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :cliff
```

pom.xml:

```
               <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                                <server>CliffTomcatServer</server>
                                <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
                        </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

~/.m2/settings.xml:

```
   <server>
      <id>CliffTomcatServer</id>
      <username>cliff</username>
      <password>beer</password>
    </server>
```

/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/conftomcat_users.xml:

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <user username="cliff" password="beer" roles="manager,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

Added to pom.xlm: http://localhost:8080/manager/text

```
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/cliff-2.3.0  
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fcliff-2.3.0
2052/127150 KB   
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Broken pipe
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fcliff-2.3.0
2356/127150 KB   
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Broken pipe
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fcliff-2.3.0
2052/127150 KB   
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Broken pipe
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fcliff-2.3.0
2156/127150 KB   
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] CLIFF ............................................. SUCCESS [  1.523 s]
[INFO] common ............................................ SUCCESS [  1.718 s]
[INFO] stanford-entity-extractor ......................... SUCCESS [  0.359 s]
[INFO] cliff ............................................. FAILURE [ 12.664 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.735 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-26T11:04:23-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) on project cliff: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Broken pipe -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :cliff
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:CLIFF davidlaxer$
```

Comment: [INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2Fcliff-2.3.0
2300/127150 KB [INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Broken pipe

Answer (score 15):

The role for deploying on /manager/text is "manager-script" and the Apache Tomcat Manager How-To indicates it shouldn't be applied to a user with the manager-gui role.  I use a deployment user with only the manager-script role and no others, and that uploads the WAR file fine without the broken pipe message.  If I add the manager-gui role to my deployment user, I get the broken pipe message you encounter.  Try changing your tomcat-users.xml to limit Cliff's role to the single manager-script role. Hope it helps.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

Comment: Same error: Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) on project cliff: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Broken pipe    <user username="cliff" password="beer" roles="manager-script"/>

Comment: Great thanks for this explanation. It was hard to find that deployer users should have only manager-script. No need maven settings.xml and all other things. just need config tomcat7-maven-plugin with username and password.

Answer (score 15):

When I set in the ~/.m2/settings.xml,it does not work. So I set in the pom.xml,like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat7-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>tomcat</server>
        <username>admin1</username>
        <password>admin1</password>
        <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
        <update>true</update>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml file, in `<tomcat-users>` element, add as follows:

```
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin1" password="admin1" roles="manager-script"/>
```

Then it works for me. :)

Comment: The message might not entirely be clear if you already have an web application deployed.
You can also add <update>true</update> to the configuration to allow deployment to update your existing webapplication.

Answer (score 6):

You may need to add this

```
<configuration>
   ..
   <update>true</update>
   ..
</configuration>
```

to your pom.xml file to run

```
mvn tomcat7:deploy
```

Comment: this helped me really

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when running `mvn tomcat7:deploy` instead of `mvn tomcat7:redeploy`.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should check the `webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml` file to ensure your `.war` file is smaller than the configured value.

```
  <max-file-size>152428800</max-file-size>
  <max-request-size>152428800</max-request-size>
```

See this question: [IBM MobileFirst Platform 6.3 Operational Analytics Failed installation for Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370317/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-6-3-operational-analytics-failed-installation-for-tomca)

Answer (score 1):

If you're running CentOS, you may need to install additional management libraries:

```
yum install tomcat-webapps tomcat-admin-webapps
```

On other platforms solution may be similar.

Comment: On Ubuntu the extra package with the manager webapp is called tomcat6-admin, tomcat7-admin and so on per tomcat version.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to use the mvn redeploy shortcut since I merged in the code that split it into a few mvn modules.  I recommend copying the .war file from webapp/target to the tomcat webapps dir on your computer/server.

Comment: Ok.  What about changing the roles? As per Mark Hattrup's answer?  Change the role back to the original?

Comment: his suggestion is good - I'm not a tomcat expert so it does sound like "manager-script" is the correct role to use for a script to upload a war via the admin control panel.  I'll update my code locally and see if it lets me upload again (however I remember thinking it was more of an mvn-library problem).

Answer (score 0):

if you already have the same application deploy on the tomcat server you need to undeploy it first. If you deploy it again it can give your the connection error.