# Maven WAR deployment issue with tomcat 8

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I am trying to deploy the WAR file form maven to tomcat8. I did the following configuration for this and ran mvn tomcat7:deploy command.

1. Added the specific roles in tomcat-users.xml
2. Added the tomcatserver in maven settings.xml
3. Added the tomcat maven plugin in pom.xml

Still getting the below error.

```
INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/BeecroftShoppingWeb  
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FBeecroftShoppingWeb&update=true
2080/5359 KB   
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Broken pipe
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FBeecroftShoppingWeb&update=true
2110/5359 KB   
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Broken pipe
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FBeecroftShoppingWeb&update=true
2092/5359 KB   
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Broken pipe
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FBeecroftShoppingWeb&update=true
2078/5359 KB   
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.987 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-23T23:10:26-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/207M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project BeecroftShoppingWeb: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Broken pipe -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mvn tomcat7:deploy - Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Broken pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230962/mvn-tomcat7deploy-cannot-invoke-tomcat-manager-broken-pipe)

Comment: @Alien, solution given in that link didn't worked for me. Finally i solved this problem by changing the pom.xml. I used http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text instead of http://localhost:8080/manager/text. This may help someone.